# Is this sufficient text cleaning in a PHP Form?

Tags: php

Wondering if the following is sufficient for sanitizing input in a simple contact form that contains inputs for `$name`, `$email`, `$phone`, and `$text`. Thanks!

There is no SQL.

I am simply wondering if I am doing this right.

```
<?php

$name = $email = $phone = $text = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $name = test_input ($_POST['name']);
    $email = test_input ($_POST['email']);
    $phone = test_input ($_POST['phone']);
    $text = test_input ($_POST['text']);
}

function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Tom, as the question stands right now, it is quite pointless. If those variables are not used for anything - as the code supposedly shows - then you don't need to worry about them at all, right? So if it's not SQL - what IS it? are these values output to the webpage? Are they used to send an email? Are they 3D printed out and made into a sandwich? Context matters - and what context your data is being used in, is the main point of validation. What type of validation you need depends 100% on what you're using the data for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `htmlspecialchars($data)` is probably fine if your program is only interacting with HTML, so in your simple example, that's probably ok. But as your programs get more complicated and the data gets passed to different environments, then that won't cut it anymore. For example, the strings which are dangerous in HTML are different from the strings which are dangerous in JavaScript, or SQL, or Bash, or _____, etc. So as the number of environments that you use increases, your cleaners have to become more and more complex. More complex cleaners means more room to make a mistake, or introduce a security vulnerability.

---

The more general question with text sanitization is "which characters are dangerous?", and that entirely depends on what you plan to do with the data after you've cleaned it. So to answer the question fully, we'd need to know which programming languages / libraries / system calls you're handing that data too.

One general suggestion I can make about text cleaning is that a whitelisting approach is always better than a cleaning approach. Let me define those terms:

- A **Cleaning Approach** is where the programmer says "Let me remove dangerous characters, and then continue using your text". So for example the user input string `"<script>malicious()</script>"`, that would get cleaned to `"scriptmaliciousscript"`, and the program keeps on chugging.
- A **whitelisting Approach** is to ask "does the input string match what I was expecting? Yes? Then let it through. No? Then reject it and return an error.".

99.99% of the time a whitelisting approach is better, here are some potential problems with cleaning that I can think of off the top of my head:

1. **User confusion** -- for example, let's say you've decided that underscore is a dangerous character, then a user enters the email address `"jim_smith@example.com"` and your cleaner silently changes it to `"jimsmith@example.com"`, they will be very confused and frustrated when their login fails.
2. **Cleaners are tricky to write properly** -- the more environments your data crosses, the more complicated the cleaner. To see what I mean, think about the cleaner you would need in order to allow a user to enter JavaScript, but detect harmful SQL, not easy. Escaping characters can be another good approach, more on that below.
3. **Hackers enjoy trying to break cleaners** -- When a hacker sees that their input is being cleaned and then processed, the game becomes "what can I type in, that the cleaner will *make malicious* for me? Hackers can be surprisingly good at this game.

Point (2) is a problem with Blacklings blockers too in that you still have to put careful thought into which characters to block (based on what languages / libraries you're passing the data to). But with cleaners, in addition to checking the input for potentially malicious strings, you also have to check the output for dangerous strings because of point (3).

One option is rather than removing harmful characters, is to escape them into harmless text, ex "O'Brian" becomes "O\'Brian", and almost all web-apps will interpret \' as text, avoiding SQLi-type problems. But this gets trickier for things like email addresses and phone numbers since you have to un-escape at the end so you don't try to email `"jim\_smith@example.com"`, or hand your dialer app `"\(123\) 456\-7890"`.

---

So my suggestion is to decide which sets of characters you're going to accept for each field (keep this list as small as you can get away with) and reject input that has characters outside this set. Generally letters and number are safe in all environments.

For example, for email addresses you only need `{Uppercase Alpha, Lowecase Alpha, Numbers, _, ., @}`, and additionally you could check for the format `____@___.___`.

For phone numbers you only need `{Numbers, (, ), 0, +}`, and can check for common formats.

For names you only really need `{Uppercase Alpha, Lowecase Alpha, space}`. Depending on who you're writing the software for, you may be asked to support things like:

- Hyphen (-) which is part of some people's names, like "John Smith-Jones", but is dangerous on command lines, as in `rm -rf`.
- Apostrophe (') which is part of some people's names, like "O'Brian", but is dangerous for SQL.
- Accent characters
- Non-roman character sets

In which case you'll have to do more digging to find out what the specific risks are with each of those.

Comment: excellent answer, thank you. i agree that a blacklist approach is better, i will be making this change. however it seems like more work for a simple contact form. i will only we using the data for internal use and contacting users about products. i just want to protect the site from malicious code.

Comment: Good answer. I would extend and say that what sanitising you need to do also depends on what you want to allow. If it makes no sense to allow users to input HTML etc, just don't allow it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert but I do use "The Whitelist Approach", I learned the process is called so afterwards.

The simple function which I do use heavily is

```
preg_replace()
```

Example for numerics:

`$_filtered = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $_foo)`

and then

`$dbh->prepare($_query)` PDO Prepared Statements For Later SQL Part.

Comment: I would call this a Blacklist Approach, since the definition of Whitelist is that you "Terminate on suspicious input" ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_input_and_output_handling#Whitelist_or_Blacklist.3F)), or accept things which match the Good Pattern and reject all else, rather than replacing things which are known to be bad, like I think your regex is doing.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth : Followed your wiki link it says : A Whitelist is "A, B and C is good (and everything else is bad)" Here 0-9 are good everything else [^ ] is bad. Logic fits for Whitelist. Correct me if I am wrong. Cheers !

Comment: @SanjeedSarkar Fair enough, but my question is: if it does not match your good pattern, do you **terminate** with an error code, or do you do a replace and continue processing?

Comment: @Mike: Good Point. Now that you mentioned it, I am aware of my ignorance in that section. I realized that sometimes I terminate, sometimes ( or mostly) I just replace and continue.